# Error when loading bootstrap into Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I am getting the below error when I am running my jasmine test case in node.
This modal() dialog is basically a bootstrap component.

**TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function**

So I am adding jquery and bootstrap into my node environment for jasmine testing.But it is failing with the below error. Can anyone help?

```
require('./support/jquery');
require('./support/bootstrap');
```

**Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set jQuery as global ?

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order when adding references. You need to add **JQuery first then  Bootstrap**. Or be sure than you download these all components via bower or npm **but not from different package managers** It may `cause an error.